# How to install a specific version of vim (+clipboard)

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

I'm trying to enable copying to OSX's clipboard in vim and most resources I have found say that I need a version of vim with `+clipboard`. These resources also indicate that this should be as easy as running `brew install vim`, however, I am stuck with `-clipboard` even after updating. Any suggestions as to how to force this feature? Do I even need it to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a `brew update` `brew install vim` should give you vim with `+clipboard`.
However your path probably still points to the old vim. Try that:

```
alias vim="/usr/local/bin/vim"
```

<strike>probably this will also work:</strike> (Not anymore, see the Update)

```
brew install vim --with-override-system-vim
```

Addition: I recommend to install it with `brew install vim --with-client-server` so you will have `+xterm_clipboard`.

Alternativly you could install macvim which should have all these features already in:

```
brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

## Update

`--with-override-system-vim` was removed. The best solution in my opinion is to just add macvim in front of your `PATH`:

```
PATH="/Users/user/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

You can test if vim points to the right instance with `which vim`

Comment: `--with-override-system-vim` simply produces `Error: invalid option: --with-override-system-vim`

Comment: @Len Yep that option was removed: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/41128 see my update